# compatibility issue with input search button and search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this search button that open a top bar on screen width less than 1080px but I have a problem on mobile with it... touching the button on mobile, the bar it doesn't appear here you have an example http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/alanic/index.html

this is the functionality:

- on screen > 1080px: the white line appears clicking on the search button
- on screen <= 1080px: the white top search bar appears clicking on the search button and the white line is set as display: none

snippet below:

```js
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}
function toggle() {
 var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1'); 
 if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
  
  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '0px';
  }, true);

  document.getElementById('demo-3').addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '-60px';
  }, true);

 } else if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
  document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
 }

}
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}
#demo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  top: -60px; }
#demo-1 input[type="search"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0.9;}
.subheader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 100%; }
#demo-2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 300; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"] {
  background: url(http://localhost/alanic/images/searchbutton.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:hover {
  background-color: none; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background-color: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: auto; }
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
 #demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
    display: none; } }
 #demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
  <input id="demo-3" type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>   
<div class="subheader">
  <form id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure though but my guess is that some mobile devices won't recognize mouse events so you may try [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Comment: I tried touch events and it doesn't work